# Is it possible to do donut caching in Varnish?

Tags: caching, distributed-caching, varnish, http-caching

I'm an ASP.NET developer trying to learn a little bit more about how caching is done on open-source stacks. I was wondering if it's possible to do donut caching on Varnish like [how you can with ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/05/donut-caching-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx).

I realize that Varnish is a distributed caching system whereas the ASP.NET MVC example is local caching, but is it possible to implement that type of behavior in Varnish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the term "donut caching", but from the description on that page, it sounds similar to Edge Side Includes:

http://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/ESIfeatures

Comment: Donut caching is the ability to only cache part of a page - for instance, if 90% of your pages contained content that changed relatively infrequently but you had one 10% that changed in real time, you could simply cache around the donut hole (the 10%).